# How to display last login activity using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql called userlog having entries such as username, logintime,userIp and Id (AI). So when I login to portal, I wanted to display last login time not present login time. I have used.
`SELECT * from userlog where con_id=" .$id . " ORDER BY loginTime DESC LIMIT 1`
This is just displaying current login time But i needed last login time and also how to achieve if user logins for first time.

Userlog is

```
CREATE TABLE `userlog`(`s_id` int NOT NULL,`con_id` int DEFAULT NULL,`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`userIp` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,`loginTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Below are the php codes

```
//Userlog
$userlog_query = $con->prepare("SELECT * from userlog where con_id=" . $_SESSION['user']['con_id'] . " ORDER BY loginTime DESC LIMIT 1");

if (!$userlog_query->execute()) {
    $loginTime = $userlog_query_row['loginTime'];
    $ip = $userlog_query_row['userIp'];
} else {
    $loginTime = "First Time Logged in";
    $ip="First Time Logged in";
}
//Username
$user_query = $con->prepare("SELECT * from contact where con_id=" . $_SESSION['user']['con_id']);
$user_query->execute();
$user_row = $user_query->fetch();
$username = $user_row['username'];

//userlog
$uip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$userlog1_query = $con->prepare("INSERT into userlog(con_id,username,userIp)values('".$_SESSION['user']['con_id']."','$username','$uip')");
$userlog1_query->execute();
```

PHPMYADMIN snaps:

[image: userlog Table]

Comment: Sounds like you are updating before running this select. Do it in the opposite order. Also looks like you could be open to SQL injections. Parameterized queries should be used. Additionally, if you only want `logintime` use that instead of the `*`.

Comment: Since we have no idea what's in your `userlog` table, we can't really help you. Don't assume we know your application or your data. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need more guidance on how to structure your question and what to include.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The table definition is useful, but it's only half the story. It doesn't tell us anything about the **contents** of the table. If you're asking us how to get the last login time, then we need to see an example of how you're storing that data (along with the current login time, presumably). Show us some relevant rows from your table, and explain which one you're trying to access. As the first commenter says, the order you do things in PHP could also be significant here too.

Comment: We need to see the PHP interaction. Where do you `select` and where does the `update` take place?

Comment: That only shows us one row of data. Presumably that's the "present login"? (You showed us the data, but failed to explain what it represents - again, **we don't know your system**, please always provide context.) Anyway, where are the rows showing earlier logins, which is presumably what you're trying to retrieve? (If you don't have such rows, then clearly you will not be able to retrieve them.)

Comment: P.S. There's really no point in using prepared statements if you aren't also going to parameterise the query! For proper security and better syntax-checking of your SQL, please use parameters. See simple examples of correct usage at  https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli (for mysqli) or https://phpdelusions.net/pdo (for PDO)

Comment: P.P.S. The second query to retrieve the username seems to be an inefficient waste of time. You could already get exactly the same field from the userlog table. Or at least you could do a single query using a JOIN to get both the contact and userlog data out in one set of results (and if there's a possibility that there's no entry in userlog, use a LEFT JOIN from contacts to userlog).

Comment: P.P.P.S. The logic of the whole block starting with `if (!$userlog_query->execute()) {` is total nonsense. It seems it would only display the login time if the query crashed - which makes no sense! And even then, there's no such variable as `$userlog_query_row` either. So I'm assuming either it always goes to the `else` block and just displays "first time logged in" (which also makes no sense - you aren't testing whether any rows were returned or not, so you can't know this), or it fails, goes to the `if` block and then maybe errors due to the nonexistent variable.

Comment: Also we can't see where you're actually displaying $loginTime or $ip, so we've no idea if they're being overwritten or something after this code runs.

Comment: Thank You @ADyson Finally got the point and will make corrections for all queries as per security issue.